# Не работает else при добавлении input

Tags: python, input, if

Не работает else при добавлении input . Всегда пишет, что "правильно".

```
chislo = input("Введи число: ")

chislo = 14

if chislo == 14:
    print("правильно")

else:
    print("неправильно")
```

Comment: Эм, ну вы строкой выше присвоили в chislo 14. А lasd вообще нигде не используется… ‍♂️

Comment: Алексей, я не знаю откуда там lasd, в первой строке в место него написано chislo(у меня лично)
 - отредачил.

Comment: Так же я пробовал добавлять int после if - if int(chislo) == 14
Не помогло

Comment: `chislo = 14` и сразу же `if chislo == 14` ..

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, всегда ответ "правильно" потому что у во второй строке кода всегда присваивается значение 14, нужно эту строку убрать.

А работать без неё правильно не будет из-за того, что функция `input` возвращает строку (`str`), а вам нужно целое число (`int`). Значит, нужно строку приобразовать в число с помощью функции `int()`.

`chislo = int(input("Введи число: "))`

Так выглядит код полностью:

```
chislo = int(input("Введи число: "))

if chislo == 14:
    print("правильно")

else:
    print("неправильно")
```